# VolatileWrite booleans

Tags: .net, multithreading

Where is the problem?

```
bool stillSingleClick = false;

// does not compime
System.Threading.Thread.VolatileWrite(ref stillSingleClick, true);
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Thread.VolatileWrite(ref
>   object, object)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Why do I ask.. I try to differentiate my doubleClick in the following way:

```
volatile bool stillSingleClick = false;

void SegmentLine_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SegmentLine line = sender as SegmentLine;

    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        stillSingleClick = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread(
            new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                delegate()
                {
                    line.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime * 2);
                                if (stillSingleClick) // HERE ALWAYS TRUE!!!
                                {
                                    SelectSegmentLine(line);
                                }
                                stillSingleClick = false;
                            }
                    ));
                }
        ));
        thread.Start();
    }
    else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        stillSingleClick = false; // HERE SHOULD BE SET IN FALSE !!!
        DisplaySegmentLineInfo(line);
    }
}
```

Does not work `stillSingleClick` is always in True....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no overloads for [`VolatileWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatilewrite.aspx) for Boolean fields, basically.

Any reason not to just use a volatile field to start with? Or you could use a field of a different type, as cdhowie suggested.

Personally I get nervous trying to write lock-free code. It's so easy to get wrong. Are there any alternatives to your current design using higher-level building blocks? If you're using .NET 4, the new Tasks Parallel Library can be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

`VolatileWrite` has no overload for operating on `bool` variables.  I have had this same problem with the `Interlocked` class.  My workaround was to use an `int` instead, using 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`.  It's a nasty hack, but it works.

Comment: +1 @cdhowie Yes it does feel wrong to use ints, but I have to do exactly the same on occasion. If feels even wronger when you have to have consts for True and False :)

Comment: so, why didn't you just use volatile booleans, like Jon proposed?

Comment: @serhio: The `volatile` keyword does support CAS operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think your real problem is that `Thread.Sleep` should be put before the call to `Invoke`, not inside. I'm guessing line.Dispatcher.Invoke executes the action on the UI thread. So the second click will set stillSingleClick to false only after the action finished.

Answer (score 0):

VolativeWrite has no overload for boolean.